# Android:How to make widget not showing in launcher widget list

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher

I have a android app,it contains a widget ,when the app is launched the widget will be showing ,and i don't want make it to public(make it not showing in widget list).
Does someone knows how to make widget in "private".